# Product page not loading <head> after Magento 2.3.2 update

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have recently updated from Magento 2.3.0 to Magento 2.3.2 and everything seems to be ok, apart from the product page (and example is here: https://staging.propmasters.net/james-bond-octopussyrupee-bank-note )

It just loads with the gallery spinner showing and looking at the html there doesn't appear to be anything loading in the

I've connected to the site via SSH and ran:

bin/magento cache:flush
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
bin/magento indexer:reindex

But it's still showing the same. I can't work out why it's doing it

Comment: it is showing 500 error in network, is there any error in log ?

Comment: what happens when you switch to default theme ?

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue with my custom theme. I have fixed it by remove:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media.image" template="product/view/gallery.phtml"/>
```

in file catalog_product_view.xml in my custom theme.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, but that line is not in my catalog_product_view.xml